# Django - query for to give rows where one column Not equals to another column in same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My model have 3 fields

```
class Table(models.Model):
    in_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True) 
    actual_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

i want to fetch results in this way :

```
select * from Table where in_time > '2013-12-31 00:00:00' and in_time != actual_time
```

So can anyone help me in completing this

```
result = Table.objects.filter(in_time__gte = '2013-12-31 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you are searching for is:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

**SOLUTION**:

```
from django.db.models import F
from datetime import datetime

min_date = datetime(2013,12,31)
result = Table.objects.filter(in_time__gte=min_date).\
exclude(in_time__eq=F('actual_time'))
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) with `~` operator to build negated (NOT) query:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Q, F

Table.objects.filter(~Q(in_time=F('actual_time')),
                     in_time__gt=datetime.datetime(2013,12,31))
```

And [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) to reference fields on same model:

> Django provides F expressions to allow such comparisons. Instances of
>   F() act as a reference to a model field within a query. These
>   references can then be used in query filters to compare the values of
>   two different fields on the same model instance.

Comment: @ProfHase85 what difference in perfomance between using exclude filter and filtering with Q class?

Comment: sorry, my fault, just got it wrong. There is no obvious performance difference.
Still initializing an extra class for a query (if there is a way to perform this without the Q class) seems cumbersome. (But it is just a matter of taste)